# Visualforce page view state size limit OR de-reference a null object for transient attachment error

Tags: attachment, dml, viewstate

I have the below Visualforce page & controller class for a user to select a design document type & upload a file. Document_Type__c is a picklist and should be required.

The code below works except in 1 situation. If you choose a file and click upload, it uploads the file without confirming the Document Type has been selected. This gives the view state size limit error.

When changing line 8 to

```
if (attachment == null) 
   transient Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
```

this ensures the Document Type is selected first but when trying to upload a file, it returns the de-reference a null object error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Visualforce page:

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Case" extensions="CreateDesignDocumentExtensionController">

<apex:messages />
    <apex:form id="theForm">

        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:variable var="a" value="{!newDesignDoc}" />

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField label="Document Type" value="{!a.Document_Type__c}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Upload"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex controller:

```
    public with sharing class CreateDesignDocumentExtensionController {

    public final Case designCase;
    public Design__c newDesignDoc { get; set; }

    public Attachment attachment {
        get {
            if (attachment == null) attachment = new Attachment();
            return attachment;
        }
        set;
    }

    public CreateDesignDocumentExtensionController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        designCase = (Case)stdController.getRecord();
        newDesignDoc = new Design__c();
    }

    public PageReference save() {       

        if (attachment.body == null) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Choose file to upload'));

        } else {

            try {
                newDesignDoc.Case__c = designCase.Id;
                insert newDesignDoc;
                attachment.parentId = newDesignDoc.Id;
                insert attachment;
            }
            catch (DMLException e) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
                return null;
            }
            finally {
                newDesignDoc.Document_Type__c = null;
                newDesignDoc = new Design__c();            
                attachment.body = null;
                attachment = new Attachment();
            }

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully'));
            return null;
        }  

        PageReference page = ApexPages.currentPage();
        //page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
     }
}
```

Comment: If all else fails you can check the value of document type via JS and return false if null preventing the command button action from executing: `<apex:commandButton onclick="return validateType();" action="{!save}" value="Upload"/>`

Comment: i looked at some of my code that does uploads and I tend to bind the `inputFile` attributes to transient variables in the controller and then in the `save` page action method, instantiate an `Attachment` sobject from the transient variables - then insert.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the "return null" statement in the Exception - I am wondering is that is preventing the finally from executing, and so the attachment never gets set back to new, and is being maintained in the viewstate?

Comment: A return is the only thing that would stop a finally block from occurring.